# Webhook to specific organisation within account

Tags: webhooks, xero-api

Where do I specify which specific organisation within my account a webhook should be monitoring?

Answer (score 2):

If you have webhooks enabled for your app, you will receive events for all orgs connected to your app. Each event will have a tenantId that you can use to see which org the event is for.

Put another way, your app either has webhooks on for ALL organisations or none.

You can get more details about this here: [https://developer.xero.com/documentation/webhooks/overview#devx-app:~:text=Tenant%20ID%09The%20ID%20of%20the%20tenant%20that%20the%20event%20happened%20in%20relation%20to%20(e.g.%20OrganisationID)](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/webhooks/overview#devx-app:%7E:text=Tenant%20ID%09The%20ID%20of%20the%20tenant%20that%20the%20event%20happened%20in%20relation%20to%20(e.g.%20OrganisationID))

Comment: Thank you Steven, for pointing us in the right direction 